# Как найти и вызвать файл в jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Здравствуйте, не могу найти файл и вызвать его.
есть проект структура папок -

```
    web
     |--images
     |     |-hello.jpg
     |--WEB-INF
     |     |-jsp
     |        |- index.jsp
```

пытаюсь в index.jsp вызвать файл, который лежит в папке images

```
<img alt="" src="/WEB-INF/images/hello.jpg" >
```

не получается. Потом решил, создам файл, найду его, и буду хоть понимать где я нахожусь.

в index.jsp добавил

```
<%
file = new File("qwer.jpg");
file.createNewFile();
out.println(file.exists());
%>
```

я так понимаю он создался, но его нигде нет. В рабочей директории tomcata смотрел нету и на рабочем месте, где проект, тоже его нет.
Помогите, как мне из папки images вызвать файлы?

---

заметил что если создать jsp файл в папке web и вызвать картинку в нем, то всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй убрать картинки из WEB-INF

```
WEB-INF
|  
| -jsp
    |- index.jsp
images
|-  hello.jpg
```

Тогда должен работать

```
<img alt="" src="/images/hello.jpg" />
```

Comment: я в jsp сделал следующее:
<%String s = new File("").getAbsolutePath();%>
мне в ответ пришло С:eclipse

Comment: Не, смотри, если файл лежит в WEB-INF, то тогда путь к нему нужно будет получать через контекст сервлета:
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/myfile");

Если файл лежит не в WEB_INF, тогда он будет доступен из classpath.

Comment: Ок. папку images положил на директорию выше, но при вызове <img alt="" src="/images/hello.jpg" > тоже не работает(

Comment: Попробуй так:
<img alt="" src="<c:url value="/images/hello.jpg" />" >

Если не сработает скинь какая ошибка возникает (в режиме разработчика можно видеть подгружаемые файлы в браузере)

Comment: не получается, Status Code:302